# Accessing device contact list using Corona Sdk?

Tags: coronasdk, contact-list

I am working on a project which fetches the contact list and the user will be able to send an email. Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated. I know it can be done in phone-gap.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the contact list is not possible with Corona.

You could consider making Facebook work with your app : http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/facebook/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use a plugin you can do everything you need. [Here](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2013/08/13/access-to-ios-contacts/) is a good place to start.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.